# How to install ruamel.yaml w/o native extension

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I'd like to install ruamel.yaml on an environment which does not have a compiler, and I do not care about the performances.

What is the proper way to install ruamel.yaml w/o pip trying to build the extension and failing to execute the C compiler which is not installed?

I ran

```
pip3 install ruamel.yaml
```

which failed with

```
building '_ruamel_yaml' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/ext
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c ext/_ruamel_yaml.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/ext/_ruamel_yaml.o
unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-myos8iv1/ruamel.yaml/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-vuvr4aoi/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-myos8iv1/ruamel.yaml/
```

Comment: Not being able to compile the C extension should not break the pip install, if it does that is a bug. You don't need the C extensions, the .py files tests if they are available. The easiest (if you are on Linux or Windows) might be to download the appropriate ruamel.yaml wheel file and install that, especially if you already have the wheel package on your platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing if compilation worked and skipping compiling the C extensions if it didn't, was removed from `ruamel.yaml` when it was no longer dependent on `libyaml` being available.

That of course doens't mean that the C compiler is available, so this should be considered a regression. In `ruamel.yaml>=0.15.41` this should be fixed.