# ruamel.yaml w/out C compiler on ARM

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I am trying to install ruamel.yaml on a raspberry Pi system without a C compiler and encounter a build error installing `ruamel.yaml.clib` (pasted below).

I see this was previously addressed for `ruamel.yaml>=0.15.41, <0.16.0` ([How to install ruamel.yaml w/o native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046012/how-to-install-ruamel-yaml-w-o-native-extension)).

Note in the output below that the `path from buildroot` is not valid on the device running pip install but is from the device that built the image.

```
$ pip install ruamel.yaml~=0.16
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting ruamel.yaml~=0.16
  Using cached ruamel.yaml-0.17.10-py3-none-any.whl (108 kB)
Collecting ruamel.yaml.clib>=0.1.2; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" and python_version < "3.10"
  Using cached ruamel.yaml.clib-0.2.6.tar.gz (180 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2t0ptfu4/ruamel-yaml-clib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2t0ptfu4/ruamel-yaml-clib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-zdtfb19x
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-2t0ptfu4/ruamel-yaml-clib/
    Complete output (3 lines):
    sys.argv ['/tmp/pip-install-2t0ptfu4/ruamel-yaml-clib/setup.py', 'egg_info', '--egg-base', '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-zdtfb19x']
    test compiling /tmp/tmp_ruamel_5les1064/test_ruamel_yaml.c -> test_ruamel_yaml compile error: /tmp/tmp_ruamel_5les1064/test_ruamel_yaml.c
    Exception: command '{path from buildroot}/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

A preferred solution would be to have a `ruamel.yaml.clib` wheel for ARM architectures or to make `clib` dependency optional (`pip install ruamel.yaml[clib]`)

Comment: Is it possible to make the clib dependency optional for ARM archtitecture only? I don't want the (majority of) users that have a wheel for their architecture, have to change their installs

Comment: Questions, and answers, on [so] should be a single coherent whole. So there should be no `UPDATE:` or `EDIT:` entries. Others can easily see that a post has been edited/improved, and what changes where made, if they are interested.

Comment: My main concern is that when clib needs to be built from source, the install will fail unless the user has previously installed a c compiler. I agree it would be better to default installing clib, but I'm not sure how that could be spec'd to exclude a default requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this broke after 0.16, but I'll try to have a look as to why this fails again (it might be that setuptools now throws a different Exception that is not caught).

Wheels for `ruamel.yaml.clib` in `aarch64` architecture are availalbe on [piwheels](https://www.piwheels.org/project/ruamel-yaml-clib/).

You should be able to install those after adding:

```
[global]
extra-index-url=https://www.piwheels.org/simple
```

to `/etc/pip.conf`.

Disclaimer: I have no control over how wheels on piwheels are generated.

Comment: It looks like the pip is searching piwheels too, but there is no wheel for python 3.8

Comment: Sorry I missed, I saw four packages and assumed without inspecting close enough that they were for 3.6/3.7/3.8/3.9. New glasses might be appropriate. Do you happen to know if the manylinux2014_aarch64 wheels from e.g. [pyzmq](https://pypi.org/project/pyzmq/#files) work for both arm6l and arm7l as provided on piwheels?

Comment: Just tested `pyzmq` and that did install.

```
Collecting pyzmq
  Downloading pyzmq-22.1.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (1.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.8 MB 4.5 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pyzmq
Successfully installed pyzmq-22.1.0

```